# Different behavior when using the output of open() vs. saving to a variable

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings in python, and I want to find which ones do not contain any bad substrings, which I read from a file.  Here's my code in python 2:

```python
with open("badchars.txt", "w") as f:
  f.write("a b c")

mywords = ["good", "bad"]

print [
       word for word in mywords
          if all(
                 badchar not in word
                    for badchar in open("badchars.txt").read().split()
                )
      ]

with open("badchars.txt") as f:
  print [
         word for word in mywords
            if all(
                   badchar not in word
                      for badchar in f.read().split()
                  )
        ]
```

I expect both lines to print ["good"], but while the first one behaves as expected, the second one gives ["good", "bad"].  I don't understand why.

The same thing happens in python 3, if I change `print` to `print()`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: this formatting is very difficult to understand, I suggest changing it to get better assistance :)

Comment: `f.read()` starts from the *current location in the file*. Thus, when you call it twice, the second time there's nothing more left to read.

Comment: The first one reads the file over and over from the beginning. The second one opens it just once, reads it to the end... and then in all future iterations reads from the end to the end, thus getting nothing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah I got it now, this was a stupid mistake.  If you post that as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: illustration of Charles's point: `with open("badchars.txt") as f:  print(f.read(), f.read())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f.read()` starts from the current location in the file. Thus, when you call it twice for the same file object, the second time there's nothing more left to read.